# Stack Exchange site to ask Visa and passport related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about Passports and Visas?

Is there a Stack Exchange site for this?

Comment: What kinds of questions? There is [travel.se] for... travel related questions, but I am not active there, so you would need to read their help center to see what is on topic there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Travel Stack Exchange](http://travel.stackexchange.com)'s [help center](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says you can ask about visas:

> customs & border crossing, visas and other travel documents such as permits

They also have a [passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passports) tag.

The [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) is also available for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis.

Do check out the help centers of these sites before you ask to make sure your question is on topic.